# aligning table view cell text label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textlabel

Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2

I've got a UITableView with Table View Cell which has it's Label, and these all show up in the storyboard.

The label is inset from the cell by what appears to be a distance of 15, although I think this will be different on different devices.

This is a link to a screen shot

[image]

I've been trying to make it the label flush with the cell.  The nearest I've got to this is

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -15, bottom: 0, right: 30)
```

which does the left margin but not the right. (I'll have to change the value 15 for different devices)

I've tried doing this in Auto Layout, but it seems I'm not able to add constraints to this label.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Ian

Comment: Set Leading, trailing, top, bottom and set require constant whatever you want. I think It will resolve this problem.

Comment: change the tabelViewCell style to Custom in attributes inspector and add label inside the content view then set the constraints leading = -15 and trailing = -15.

Comment: Thanks for both these replies.  I've used 'Basic' when adding a prototype cell, and it seems that this won't let me add constraints to the UILabel in the cell.  Also, the -15 is, I think, different for different devices.  However, I realise that if I use 'Custom' instead of 'Basic' I should have all the control I need over the UILabel.  Also, but of a delay getting back to you - time difference here in Australia.